# In Vue.JS method on passed string trim() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am trying to remove white space from one of the returned object's property with .trim() function but it doesn't work.

I already tried applying JS functions such as .replace(/\s/g,'') but it is also not working

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'navigation',
    props: ["navigation"],
    methods:{
        whiteSpace: function(a){
            var str = a;
            str.toLowerCase();
            str.trim();
            console.log(str);


            return str;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<li>
  <router-link :to="{ path: whiteSpace(nav.linkTitle) }">
       {{nav.linkTitle}}
  </router-link>
</li>
```

It should return string without white space but it doesn't remove white space.

Comment: Why are you declaring a new `var`? Just use `return a.toLowerCase().trim();` inside the whiteSpace method

Comment: I know right, I was trying to do it in so many ways...

Answer (score 3):

The `trim` method does not modify the object, it returns a new string.

just return with `return str.trim()`

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
str.toLowerCase();
```

returns a new value. It doesn't modify the current value, so you should have done this:

```
var str = a;
str = str.toLowerCase();
str = str.trim();
console.log(str);
```

but any ways, you could just return the trimmed value like so:

```
export default {
    name: 'navigation',
    props: ["navigation"],
    methods: {
        whiteSpace: function (a) {
            return a.toLowerCase().trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, it transformed to a lower case, but still didin't remove white space

Comment: what is the string for nav.linkTitle?

Comment: Do you think that you may have tabs instead of spaces? You could use `return a.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').toLowerCase();` instead of trim() if the browser isn't supporting it.

Comment: if you want to remove spaces from the string you should use
a.replace(/\s/g, ''");

Comment: @NiGmAx : As a note that removes all spaces not just beginning and ending spaces.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the problem. .trim() function doesn't work, I tried `.replace(/\s/g, "");` and it helps, thank you for your help guys :)

Comment: `trim()` only gets rid of any starting and trailing whitespace (it _trims_ the spaces off the start and end of a string) - it doesn't get rid of all spaces inside the string. I think you misunderstood how trim works if you expected it to get rid of _all_ spaces.